# CakePHP Calling $this->create() in model breaks the 'created' and 'modified' automatic fields for $this->save()

Tags: cakephp, save, record

Model, abbreviated:

```
function doStuff {
    foreach(thing) {
        fields = makeFields()
        saveStuff(fields)
    }
}

function saveStuff (fields = array()) {
    if (a record with field data does not yet exist) {
    $this->save(fields)
}
```

The above creates ONE new record, and for every `foreach` iteration UPDATES that record, because Cake 'loads' the new record in memory, providing an `id` for the `$this->save()` that shouldn't be there.

The solution is `$this->create()`, but this prevents the created and modified fields from working (DB entry is zeroed, 0000-00-00 00:00:00). Any suggestions? I thought perhaps unsetting the data another way after a save, but would that also break the created/modified fields?

Using CakePHP 2.4.4

Comment: Define "not working". There is no issue with the create/modified fields related to that. This must be something within your app code. Posting "abbreviated" code doesn't help either to track the issue down.

Comment: A raw approach: `$this->id = null`. Cake will update the row if there is an `id` present. Otherwise, it will create it.

Comment: @Eagle - this doesn't work - overloaded something-or-other 'has no effect'. However, it did get me thinking about empty fields, hence the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out.

`$this->create()` loads a 'blank canvas', which would therefore, by definition, include **all** fields available in a record, with their *default values*.

In the DB, I had set the default for the `created` and `modified` fields to `0000-00-00 00:00:00`. `$this->create()` therefore fills those fields with the default values in the Model data. For the automated fill to work, they must be empty. I set default for both to none, and all's well.